# Minecraft command blocks, how do i link my boss bar to my player health

Tags: minecraft-commands

i created a scoreboard called health and i also created a boss bar named health, i'm not sure how to link the boss bar and the players health using command blocks

Comment: I know nothing about scoreboards and commands, but thinking about it from a coding standpoint... if theres a way to detect when the player takes damage, you can decrement the boss health bar by the same amount.

Comment: @Kyle Hooking into game mechanics like mods do isn't possible with commands. The best you can do is to use advancement triggers, but those don't exist for everything and they don't always execute immediately, but instead at the end of the tick or similar.

Comment: Which edition of Minecraft are you playing?

Comment: Flagging question as unclear because it does not specify which edition of Minecraft is being played.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a scoreboard objective.

Set the max value of the bossbar to 20:

```
/bossbar set minecraft:health max 20
```

Make it visible to you:

```
/bossbar set minecraft:health players @s
```

Run this command in a repeating command block:

```
execute store result bossbar minecraft:health value run data get entity @p Health
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is always true, but by my testing you can also read in the max health with data tag Attributes[0].Base. Hope this helps if you want it to work for anything with a different max health.